# MySQL запрос

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы

1 **main**:

```
id | user |   img   | gallery
-----------------------------
01 | 0001 | 001.jpg | 1
02 | 0001 | 002.jpg | 2
03 | 0001 | 003.jpg | 1
04 | 0001 | 004.jpg | 2
```

2 **gallery**:

```
id | user | title
01 | 0001 | Gallery 1
02 | 0001 | Gallery 2
```

Мне нужно сделать запрос для получения групп галерей определенного пользователя и случайным изображением. Я делаю такой запрос:

```
SELECT main.gallery AS `gallery`, count(*) AS `count`, `img` AS `img`, gallery.title AS `title` FROM `main`, `gallery` WHERE main.user = '0001' AND main.gallery = gallery.id GROUP BY `gallery`
```

В результате я получаю группу галерей определенного пользователя, но изображение всегда одно и тоже как сделать **ORDER BY RAND()** что бы изображение было всегда случайным, а порядок вывода галерей оставался одинаковым?

P.S. Возможно я в целом неправильно сделал запрос, если есть способ сделать это оптимальнее подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Изображение должно случайным в рамках галереи выбранного пользователя или вообще всех галерей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так:

```
select g.id as gallery, count(*) as count, x.img, g.title 
from (
  select gallery, img 
  from main
  where user=1
  order by rand()
) x join gallery g on g.id = x.gallery
group by g.id;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4ee6/3)

Comment: Спасибо, ушел читать про вложенные запросы :)

Answer (score 0):

Может так? Только тут без юзверей, их добавлять по вкусу.

```
create temporary table tmp (id int, gallery int, a int, g int, img varchar(20));
insert into tmp select id, gallery,
    case @g when gallery then @i := @i + 1 else @i := 1 end a,
        @g := gallery, img
        from main join (select @g := 0, @i := 0) t
        order by gallery, id;
create temporary table tmp1 (gallery int, a int);
insert into tmp1 (gallery, a) select gallery, floor(rand()*max(a)-1e-10) + 1
    from tmp group by gallery;
select tmp.id, tmp.gallery, tmp.img
    from tmp join tmp1 on tmp.gallery = tmp1.gallery and tmp.a = tmp1.a;
```

В первой временной таблице нумеруются id'ы, во второй -- случайное число умножается на максимальный порядковый номер, для получения случайного номера. Последний select выбирает id под этим порядковым номером.